# how to stop ".jfm file cannot be accessed" from locking up tfs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfignore

I'm working on a project with a large solution in TFS, which includes a sqlProject. There's a few things we use in that project but there's also a .jfm file generated for the project. The .jfm has been excluded from the project but TFS keeps trying to access it. It also shows up under "Excluded Changes" even though I have not made any changes to it.

I've added a .tfignore file with the line

```
*.jfm
```

and restarted visual studio and rebooted my computer. This popup persists:

[image]

and then I can't open anything in Source Control Explorer, it just keeps giving me the popup. I've googled, spoken to my coworkers, tried moving the .tfignore file around, none of it has worked and it's driving me bonkers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to take a [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, and if you need additional help with the site, check [this](//stackoverflow.com/help) out. Oh, and if you ever run into issues that the help page doesn't cover, feel free to ask on [meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 4):

To ignore the .jfm files you have to ensure that the .tfignore file was checked in to the remote server.

Please try following below steps to fix this issue.:

1. Delete the .jfm files from TFS via web portal (backup them if needed),
2. Restart VS, Right click the project node under the collection and
   select **Get Latest Version** to remove the .jfm files from local
   workspace.
3. Set the .tfignore file and check in to the remote server

Then try it again, if that not work, just try to add a new workspace and map the sources in VS,then check in the .tfignore file to the remote server.

Comment: @Sadie Any update for this? have you resolved the issue by this workaround?